# How do I get checkbox elements after of creating them with javascript and add some event on it?

Tags: javascript, element, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyname

I build a to do list like below but I can't get the input `type=checkbox` element  after creating it and adding an event on it right down the my block code:

[image]

```js
const getvalue = document.getElementById("add-work")
const btn = document.getElementById("btn")
const listcont = document.getElementById("listcont")

btn.addEventListener("click", e => {
  const eleme = document.createElement("p")
  const inpu = document.createElement("input")
  const tags = document.createElement("span")
  inpu.setAttribute("type", "checkbox")
  eleme.append(inpu)
  eleme.append(tags)
  tags.innerHTML += getvalue.value
  listcont.append(eleme)
  getvalue.value = ""
})
```

Comment: give it an id and add the event listener like anything else.

Comment: Where do you try to get the checkbox? You can add more details.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then update your question with some HTML in a snippet demo.

Comment: Be advised that arbitrary truncations such as `eleme` and `inpu` are likely to be viewed as typos and cause confusion. Those few characters are worth spending for code clarity. Also, tags are just text in a file. You're dealing with _elements_. Don't call your elements tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an id to the input using:

```
inpu.id = "yourid"
```

and then access the element using getElementById later in any other file.

Or add an event listener to it right away after creating it using

```
inpu.addEventListener(...)
```

Comment: Up vote for pointing out that "inpu" is already available in the function.

Comment: I did it,but when I want to get element by id,it return null

Comment: @mmdhasn most likely cause the getElementById is running before the element is created, and if u have a lot of inputs with the same id, getElementsById will grab only 1 so it's better to use querySelectorAll in this case